# How to choose a conjunctive particle: 와/과, 하고, (이)랑?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, conjunctions

*(Of course 와/과 is determined by the final consonant of the preceding noun, or lack of it).*  But, other than that, are these completely interchangeable?

**Can 와/과, 하고, (이)랑 be chosen regardless of context/situation?**

Answer (score 1):

Native Korean here :)

If you use it as a meaning of 'and', then yes, they are all usable with almost no nuance differences, other than the fact that 랑 is used more frequently in spoken language.

However, 하고 can have other meanings such as 'with (someone/something)' or 'and then' etc.

랑 can also mean 'with (someone/something).